# Android Studio, seeing all devices

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to android development and I've chosen android studio, the issue is that in the interface designer, although I've selected the device and nexus 4, I'm seeing all devices. Is there a way that I can choose to see only one device,

this is a screenshot:
[image]

I want to see the interface on only one device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a dropdown menu in the upper-left corner of the layout designer. Choose the **None** option from it.

[image: Screenshot of layout design panel]